# using count on comparing multiple row with different values in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

i have this table called `dbo_modules`and it has columns `ModuleCountLeft` and `ModuleCriticalLevel`
in my controller, im trying to get the number of modules where `ModuleCountLeft` is less than the value of `ModuleCriticalLevel`. in my table, the values of `ModuleCountLeft` and `ModuleCriticalLevel` differs from row to row. so in my controller i uses this query:

```
$critical = DB::table('dbo_modules')
                ->where('ModuleCountLeft' , '<=' , DB::table('dbo_modules')->pluck('ModuleCriticalLevel') )
                ->count();
```

the problem here is that im not getting the correct values. It get the first `ModuleCriticalLevel` and makes it the point of comparison. for example the first `ModuleCriticalLevel` in the table is 20, it compares all the `ModuleCountLeft` to 20. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? or is my code wrong? please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this:

    `$critical = count(DB::table('dbo_modules')
                    ->where('ModuleCountLeft' , '<=' , DB::table('dbo_modules')
                    ->pluck('ModuleCriticalLevel') )
                    ->get());`

Comment: will try this out thanks!

Comment: i tried this but some of records are not being counted. i manually check phpmyadmin it got 6 then what im getting is 5 only. i also tried to display it and saw that one record can't be seen. any ideas?

Comment: Are you using soft delete?

Comment: Nope. Just trying to get total number of rows where ModuleCountLeft is less than the ModuleCriticalLevel

Answer (score 1):

Try like following. You need not to pluck anything

```
$critical = DB::table('dbo_modules')
->where('ModuleCountLeft' ,'<=' ,'ModuleCriticalLevel')
->count();
```

Comment: i have tried this the weird thing is the value i got from $critical is 0 i don't know why

Comment: check if you have any data that falls in this logic or not. @BourneShady